# Connect SMTP from Proxy (SOCKS5)

Tags: python, smtp, socks

I'm willing to connect to SMTP from a proxy (socks5)

this is what i've tried so far :

**first i checked if my socks5 is working well:**

```
# test socks5
# username = 8af309b04420 , password = 1858f2fd8c , host = 185.242.108.72 , port = 12324

import requests
proxy = {"socks5": "http://8af309b04420:1858f2fd8c@185.242.108.72:12324/"}
url = 'http://example.org'
r = requests.get(url,  proxies=proxy)
print(r.status_code)
```

It returns "200" which means it connected ( no issues )

**Then i tried to connect to SMTP using my socks5, it didn't work:**

```
# SMTP connect from Socks
import smtplib
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587,
                          source_address=("http://8af309b04420:1858f2fd8c@185.242.108.72:12324/", 12324))
```

**I got this error :**

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed
```

Comment: You can't specify a proxy in the `source_address` parameter of `smtplib.SMTP()`. That parameter is meant only for binding the SMTP socket to a local network interface. In fact, nothing in the [smtplib documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html), or looking at the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/smtplib.py), suggests that use of a proxy is even supported at all. Unlike the `requests` library, which does.

Comment: This is what i found so far, thank you for confirming @RemyLebeau

Comment: SMTP and SOCKS5 are pretty basic protocols to implement manually using plain sockets, if you really need to access an SMTP server through a SOCKS proxy. See [RFC 5321](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5321) (SMTP) and [RFC 1928](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1928) (SOCKS5). And Python has [built-in support for SSL/TLS for sockets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html)